# Create Kafka connect without confluent

Tags: windows, apache-kafka-connect, oracle-cdc

I recently started with Kafka and I try to create a Kafka connect to connect to oracle but I can't do it. The information I found is about confluent, but that does't work in Windows ... How can i configure one or create it with java?

I use for my test standalone conecction:
cmd .\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties .\config\connect-bbdd.properties ->

```
name=jdbc-conector 
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector 
tasks.max=1 
connection.url=dbc:oracle:thin@localhost:xe 
connection.user: user 
connection.password: pwd 
mode = bulk 
topic.prefix=test
table.whitelist: mytable
```

Error:

```
WARN The configuration 'offset.flush.interval.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.file.filename' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
 jul 21, 2019 10:36:13 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
ADVERTENCIA: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in 
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains 
empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource 
contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.
[2019-07-21 22:36:13,886] ERROR Failed to create job for ..\config\connect-bbdd.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
[2019-07-21 22:36:13,888] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration 
is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:xe 
for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:xe
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:118)
```

...and other errors from "any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)"

Comment: Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. Which connector are you trying to use? Share what you've tried so far, and the errors you've encoutered.

Comment: I used a Kafka producer with a database connector in a Java program. Therefore, I tried to use that same connector for Kafka connect.

Answer (score 0):

The `confluent` command doesn't work natively in Windows, no.

But `connect-distributed` or `connect-standalone` are not only in Confluent, and should both work and load the JDBC connectors provided within Confluent Platform if you did download it on Windows.

Otherwise, if you have only Apache Kafka, you will need to [download JDBC Connector separately](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/) and set it up yourself via the `plugin.path` property mentioned in the Connect config files.

Answer (score 0):

This error that you get:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:xe 
for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:xe
```

is because you've not made the Oracle JDBC driver available. See https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#jdbc-drivers.

Comment: I've fixed it. I needed colon after "thin". `(dbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:xe)` and jdbc7 (i was using) was not for me. However, bulk mode doesn't work, i need use a query with my config.